# Is metric tensor invariant under rotation?

Tags: metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, models, invariants

It is said that metric tensor depend on the local coordinate system and therefore are not intrinsic to the surface of an 3d-object? How is it possible, kindly provide any proof or discussion.
Also is metric tensor invariant under rotation. If so, kindly provide discussion or proof for it.
I am new to differential geometry, it would be good if supporting reference and some good case examples are provided.

Thank you.

Comment: If you mean a rotation of your local coordinate system, then yes, it is invariant in the sense that it will still be describing the same manifold.

Comment: The representation of the metric tensor will depend on the coordinate system. For example the Schwarzschild, Gullstrand-Painlevé, Eddington-Finkelstein and Kruskal-Szekeres metrics all look very different, but they are all the same metric describing the same spacetime. Is this what your question is getting at? If not, can you clarify exactly what you're asking?

Comment: Firstly is metric tensor as such invariant under rotation. Secondly if metric tensor is calculated on manifold (surface) then is it invariant under rotation when correspondence estimation would be done on similar object but different orientation.

Answer (score 4):

I could give an example of what people mean when they "say":

> ... metric tensor depend on the local coordinate system and therefore are not intrinsic to the surface

Take for example the [Schwarzschild metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric). We have 
$$ds^2 = -\left(1-\frac{2m}{r}\right)dt^2 + \left(1-\frac{2m}{r}\right)^{-1}dr^2 +r^2(d\theta^2 +\sin^2\theta d\phi^2) $$
If you read this as $$ds^2 = dx_{\mu} \ g^{\mu \nu} \ dx_{\nu}$$
there are many choices available to you. Three (easier) examples that serve to clarify the point could be:

1. Pick your co-ordinates to be $dt, dr, rd\theta, r\sin \theta d\phi$, and then your metric tensor reads ${\rm diag}(-(1-2M/r), (1-2M/r)^{-1}, 1,1)$.
2. Co-ordinates are $dt, dr, d\theta, d\phi$, and your metric tensor reads ${\rm diag}(-(1-2M/r), r^2(1-2M/r)^{-1}, r^2,r^2 \sin^2 \theta)$.
3. A hopeless choice - Deliberately ensure that you have a Minowski metric ${\rm diag}(-1,1,1,1)$ and mess up your "co-ordinates" (absorbing square root of that (1-2M/r) factor in your co-ordinate definitions).

Of course, there are many other choices. But this conveys the basic premise. Metric tensor does depend on what co-ordinate system you are adopting.

Also, while adopting co-ordinates that are easier to work with is understandable, changing your co-ordinates isn't going to make a difference to the basic physics associated with it. For example, in the above case, you can't avoid the fact that EITHER your co-ordinates (with all the redefinition possibilities), OR your metric tensor, will become singular at $r = 2M$, with everything it leads to! (Also at $r=0$ but that's not as glaring, to me at least). One can ease the maths, but can't change the Physics by changing co-ordinates!

Comment: Hi JamalS can u simplify

Comment: @stephen: This is not my answer, I only edited it.

Comment: The point of discussion here is Riemannian metric tensor

Comment: Simplify _what_?

Comment: consider 3d object, pick manifold, find metric tensor, now how do u say this is rotation invariant when correspondence estimtion is done for similarity with new 3d object with change in orintation.