# Physical properties or invariants encoded by the combination of metric tensor/coordinate system

Tags: metric-tensor, invariants

In [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/147374/73067) it is nicely demonstrated that the numerical values $g_{\mu\nu}$ of the metric tensor depend on the coordinate system chosen or, put another way, ugly mathematical expressions can be "freely" shifted around between the tensor and the coordinate system representation.

Yet the combination metric tensor/coordinate system does represent some physical properties of the point in space-time to which they apply, I assume: which?

Comment: This is the concept of diffeomorphism covariance (or "general covariance"). The same concept exists in non-relativistic physics (3-d euclidean space). Imagine a pencil out in space, oriented in a particular direction. This pencil has definite physical properties. Its length is a scalar quantity, which does not change for any observer (in non-relativistic physics). Its orientation is a vector-quantity, which changes in a particular way under rotations of the observer. The precise orientation-vector you measure depends on your coordinate system, but it's still a physical property.

Comment: In the same way, the metric is physical but its precise components change under coordinate-transformations. The only difference with the previous example is that instead of 3-D euclidean space, we have 3+1-D Lorentzian spacetime. If you're wondering, what scalar objects can be formed with tensors, then that's just a matter of combining and contracting metrics $g_{\mu\nu}$, derivatives $\partial_\mu$, spacetime intervals $dx_{\mu}$, etc. For example, a spacetime interval $ds=g^{\mu\nu}dx_\mu dx_\nu$, the Ricci scalar $R$, the determinant of the metric $\det(g)$, etc.